# getting an error when using `npm install react-native-modal-datetime-picker` in terminal

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, npm

I am working on an app and whenever I try to install `react-native-modal-datetime-picker` package it keeps throwing an error and this is the same for any date time picker package like `@react-native-community/datetime-picker`

and this is the error that I'm getting:

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: undefined@undefined
npm ERR! Found: react@16.13.1
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"16.13.1" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer react@">=16.8.3" from @react-native-community/datetimepicker@3.0.4
npm ERR!   node_modules/@react-native-community/datetimepicker
npm ERR!     @react-native-community/datetimepicker@"3.0.4" from the root project
npm ERR!   1 more (react-native)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"17.0.1" from react-native-windows@0.64.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react-native-windows
npm ERR!   peer react-native-windows@">=0.62" from @react-native-community/datetimepicker@3.0.4
npm ERR!   node_modules/@react-native-community/datetimepicker
npm ERR!     @react-native-community/datetimepicker@"3.0.4" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See /Users/accountName/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/accountName/.npm/_logs/2jajaijajaijajajajjajajajjjaijajajjajjjjjjjjjjjjjjajjjajaijjjjjjj
```

If you have any Idea on how I can fix this please let me know...Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is issue is not completely resolved yet but if you're facing this issue please try installing the package with yarn